# Does python have any package which can get record from Web of Science or Scopus?

Tags: python

Is there any package in python that can read records from a .bib file and then get the related works from Scopus or Web of science?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It's surprising to see what all Python can do for us.

- You can read .bib files using Python's [`BibtexParser`](https://bibtexparser.readthedocs.io/en/master/)
- Access the Scopus API using [`Scopus`](https://pypi.org/project/scopus/)
- Use the [`Wos`](https://pypi.org/project/wos/) client to query Web of Science database

Comment: `wos` client will not help you unless you have a premium access.

Answer (score 1):

Already presented by [@viseshini-reddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10351455/viseshini-reddy), you can easily use [BibtexParser](https://bibtexparser.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#step-2-parse-it) to help you. For instance, by having some paper to cite [1], you can follow the next steps.

## Instructions

1.1. First of all, try to create some `bibliography.bib` file, with the following information inside, as an example:

```
@inproceedings{Calisto:2017:TTM:3132272.3134111,
 author = {Calisto, Francisco M. and Ferreira, Alfredo and Nascimento, Jacinto C. and Gon\c{c}alves, Daniel},
 title = {Towards Touch-Based Medical Image Diagnosis Annotation},
 booktitle = {Proceedings of the 2017 ACM International Conference on Interactive Surfaces and Spaces},
 series = {ISS '17},
 year = {2017},
 isbn = {978-1-4503-4691-7},
 location = {Brighton, United Kingdom},
 pages = {390--395},
 numpages = {6},
 url = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/3132272.3134111},
 doi = {10.1145/3132272.3134111},
 acmid = {3134111},
 publisher = {ACM},
 address = {New York, NY, USA},
 keywords = {Human-Computer Interaction, Interaction Design, Medical Image Diagnosis, Medical Visualization, Touch-Based},
}
```

1.2. Now, you are able to use the `bibtexparser` package;

2.1. Create a python file, for instance, `main.py`;

2.2. On the `main.py` file source, import the `bibtexparser` package:

```
import bibtexparser
```

2.3. Read the `bibliography.bib` information:

```
import bibtexparser

with open('bibliography.bib') as bibtex_file:
    bib_database = bibtexparser.load(bibtex_file)
```

2.4. From here, you can now query any kind of information of your `bibliography.bib` file:

```
import bibtexparser

with open('bibliography.bib') as bibtex_file:
    bib_database = bibtexparser.load(bibtex_file)

print(bib_database.comments)
print(bib_database.preambles)
```

This will give you the set of comments and preambles on your `bibliography.bib` file. Now, you can query the [Web of Science](http://webofknowledge.com) and/or [Scopus](https://www.scopus.com) sources from this `bibliography.bib` file.

[1] Calisto, F.M., Ferreira, A., Nascimento, J.C. and Gonçalves, D., 2017, October. Towards Touch-Based Medical Image Diagnosis Annotation. In Proceedings of the 2017 ACM International Conference on Interactive Surfaces and Spaces (pp. 390-395). ACM.